# Date and TimePicker in single popup

Tags: android

I'am new to android. Just i tried to create a datepicker dialog with timepicker. I have done that by doing some research.

This is my code

```
dataandTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                    mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
            dpd.show();
        }
    });

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(context, mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, false);
                tpd.show();
                myear=year;
                mmonth=monthOfYear;
                mday=dayOfMonth;
                nextdate = (new StringBuilder().append(myear).append("-")
                        .append(mmonth + 1).append("-").append(mday).append(" ")).toString();
            }
        };

        private OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mhour = hourOfDay;
                mminute = minute;
                nexttime = (new StringBuilder().append(mhour).append(":").append(mminute).append(":").append(msecond)).toString();
                dateandtime = nextdate+nexttime;
            }
        };
```

I'am getting date value to nextdate and time value to nexttime. After that am concatenating both the values and i assigned to dateandtime. Now i want to get the dateandtime value like 2014-12-08 12:22:58. could anyone please guide me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Probably the pattern you need is this: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Use it like:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fmt.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works, date and time in single dialog

CustomDateTimePicker.class

```
package com.example.timeanddatepicker;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class CustomDateTimePicker implements OnClickListener {
private DatePicker datePicker;
private TimePicker timePicker;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

private Calendar calendar_date = null;

private Activity activity;

private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

private Dialog dialog;

private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;
public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
        ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
    activity = a;
    iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            resetData();
        }
    });

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
}
public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
    linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
    linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

    btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
    btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
    btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
    btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
    btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
    btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
    btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
    linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

    viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
    viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

    datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
    timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            selectedHour = hourOfDay;
            selectedMinute = minute;
        }
    });

    viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
    viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

    LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
    linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

    btn_set = new Button(activity);
    btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_set.setText("Set");
    btn_set.setId(SET);
    btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
    btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
    btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
    linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

    linear_child.addView(linear_top);
    linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
    linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

    linear_main.addView(linear_child);

    return linear_main;
}
public void showDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

        datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

        dialog.show();

        btn_setDate.performClick();
    }
}

public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
    this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
}

public void dismissDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
}

public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
    if (calendar != null)
        calendar_date = calendar;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.setTime(date);
    }
}

public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
            && year < 3000) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
    }

}

public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
    if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = true;
    }
}

public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
        boolean isAM) {
    if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (hourIn12Format == 12)
            hourIn12Format = 0;

        int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

        if (!isAM)
            hourIn24Format += 12;

        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = false;
    }
}

public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
    is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
}

public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
    public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
            Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
            String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
            String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
            int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

    public void onCancel();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case SET_DATE:
        btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
        btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
        break;

    case SET_TIME:
        btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
        btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
        break;

    case SET:
        if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
            int month = datePicker.getMonth();
            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


            calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                    selectedMinute);

            iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                    calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                    getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                    getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
        }
        if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
            dialog.dismiss();
        break;

    case CANCEL:
        if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
            iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * @param date
 *            date in String
 * @param fromFormat
 *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
 *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
 * @param toFormat
 *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
 *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
 *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
 * @return formatted date
 */
public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
        String toFormat) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(d);

        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}

private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
    int hourIn12Format = 0;

    if (hour24 == 0)
        hourIn12Format = 12;
    else if (hour24 <= 12)
        hourIn12Format = hour24;
    else
        hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

    return hourIn12Format;
}

private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
    String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
            : "PM";
    return ampm;
}

private void resetData() {
    calendar_date = null;
    is24HourView = true;
}

public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
    if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
        return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
}
}
```

mainActivity.class

```
package com.example.timeanddatepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1))
                            .setText(
                                    + calendarSelected
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + ":" + monthNumber + ":" + year
                                    + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min
                                    + " " + AM_PM);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    custom.showDialog();
                }
            });

}

CustomDateTimePicker custom;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lablel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lablel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```